# Simple Machine learning model training returning Nan

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, linear-regression

I am trying to start learning ML.

I wrote a simple example:

```
import numpy as np

# Prepare the data
input = np.array(list(range(100)))
output = np.array([x**2 + 2 for x in list(range(100))])

# Visualize Data
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(input, output, 'ro')
plt.show()

# Define your Model
a = 1
b = 1

# y = ax + b # we put a bias in the model based on our knowledge

# Train your model == Optimize the parameters so that they give very less loss
for e in range(10):
    for x, y in zip(input, output):
        y_hat = a*x + b
        loss =  0.5*(y_hat-y)**2

        # Now that we have loss, we want gradient of the parameters a and b
        # derivative of loss wrt a = (-x)(y-ax+b)
        # so gradient descent: a = a - (learning_rate)*(derivative wrt a)

        a = a - 0.1*(-x)*(y_hat-y)
        b = b - 0.1*(-1)*(y_hat-y)
    print("Epoch {0} Training loss = {1}".format(e, loss))


# Make Prections on new data

test_input = np.array(list(range(101,150))) 
test_output = np.array([x**2.0 + 2 for x in list(range(101,150))])
model_predictions = np.array([a*x + b for x in list(range(101,150))])

plt.plot(test_input, test_output, 'ro')
plt.plot(test_input, model_predictions, '-')
plt.show()
```

Now when I run the code:

```
ml_zero.py:22: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in double_scalars
  loss =  0.5*(y_hat-y)**2
Epoch 0 Training loss = inf
ml_zero.py:21: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in double_scalars
  y_hat = a*x + b
Epoch 1 Training loss = inf
ml_zero.py:21: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
  y_hat = a*x + b
Epoch 2 Training loss = nan
Epoch 3 Training loss = nan
Epoch 4 Training loss = nan
Epoch 5 Training loss = nan
Epoch 6 Training loss = nan
Epoch 7 Training loss = nan
Epoch 8 Training loss = nan
Epoch 9 Training loss = nan
```

Why is the error nan? I wrote the simplest model, but with python I was getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ml_zero.py", line 20, in <module>
    loss = (y_hat-y)**2
OverflowError: (34, 'Result too large')
```

Then I converted all Python lists to numpy. Now, I get Nan error, I just don't understand why these small values are giving theses errors.

With Daniele's answer to replace the loss with mean squared loss, i.e. dividing the loss by total number of inputs, I get this output:

```
Epoch 0 Training loss = 1.7942781420994678e+36
Epoch 1 Training loss = 9.232837400842652e+70
Epoch 2 Training loss = 4.751367833814119e+105
Epoch 3 Training loss = 2.4455835946216386e+140
Epoch 4 Training loss = 1.2585275201812707e+175
Epoch 5 Training loss = 6.4767849625200624e+209
Epoch 6 Training loss = 3.331617554363007e+244
Epoch 7 Training loss = 1.714758503849272e+279
ml_zero.py:22: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in double_scalars
  loss =  0.5*(y-y_hat)**2
Epoch 8 Training loss = inf
Epoch 9 Training loss = inf
```

At least it runs, but I am trying to learn the linear function using Stochastic gradient descent, which updates parameters after each point's loss.

Still not getting how people work with these models, loss should decrease why is it increasing with gradient descent?

Comment: Do you have a debugging facility in your IDE? I'd suggest you start there by stepping through and working out where the 'bug' (either in your understanding or the code) is.

Comment: @Aidenhjj thanks, i will start debugging..however i also wanted to know if some numpy or python feature .. I am not getting

Comment: You were getting overflow on both the python and the numpy version. The number you're generating in `loss` is obviously growing to bigger than the maximum allowed in a double. You get slightly different errors because numpy uses c directly in the backend.

Comment: You are trying to fit a linear model to a quadratic function. Is this intentional?

Comment: @Dan thx, yes it is intentional. I updated the question with the parameter update logic. I don't think the maths is wrong...

Comment: Doesn't `a = (-x)(y-ax+b)` implies `a = a - 0.1*(-x)*(y-y_hat)`? Which means your update rule is off by `-1`. Not that that will fix your error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You got the math wrong. When you compute the gradient update for GD you have to divide by the number of samples in your dataset: that's why it is called **mean** squared error and not just squared error. 
Also, you might want to use smaller inputs since you're trying to work with an exponential, as it tends to grow... well, exponentially with `x`.
Look at [this post](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2014/06/24/gradient-descent-linear-regression/) for a good intro to LR and GD.

I took the liberty of rewriting your code a bit, this should work:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Prepare the data
input_ = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)  # Don't assign user data to Python's input builtin
output = np.array([x**2 + 2 for x in input_])

# Define model
a = 1
b = 1

# Train model
N = input_.shape[0]  # Number of samples
for e in range(10):
    loss = 0.
    for x, y in zip(input_, output):
        y_hat = a * x + b
        a = a - 0.1 * (2. / N) * (-x) * (y - y_hat)
        b = b - 0.1 * (2. / N) * (-1) * (y - y_hat)
        loss +=  0.5 * ((y - y_hat) ** 2)
    loss /= N

    print("Epoch {:2d}\tLoss: {:4f}".format(e, loss))


# Predict on test data
test_input = np.linspace(0, 15, 150) # Training data [0-10] + test data [10 - 15]
test_output = np.array([x**2.0 + 2 for x in test_input])
model_predictions = np.array([a*x + b for x in test_input])

plt.plot(test_input, test_output, 'ro')
plt.plot(test_input, model_predictions, '-')
plt.show()
```

This should give you as output something along these lines:

```
Epoch  0    Loss: 33.117127
Epoch  1    Loss: 42.949756
Epoch  2    Loss: 40.733332
Epoch  3    Loss: 38.657764
Epoch  4    Loss: 36.774646
Epoch  5    Loss: 35.067299
Epoch  6    Loss: 33.520409
Epoch  7    Loss: 32.119958
Epoch  8    Loss: 30.853112
Epoch  9    Loss: 29.708126
```

And this is the output plot:

[image]

Cheers

**EDIT**: OP was asking about SGD. The above answer is still valid code, but it's for standard GD (where you iterate on the whole dataset at the same time).
For SGD, the main loop must be slightly changed:

```
for e in range(10):
    for x, y in zip(input_, output):
        y_hat = a * x + b
        loss =  0.5 * ((y - y_hat) ** 2)
        a = a - 0.01 * (2.) * (-x) * (y - y_hat)
        b = b - 0.01 * (2.) * (-1) * (y - y_hat)

    print("Epoch {:2d}\tLoss: {:4f}".format(e, loss))
```

Note that I had to lower the learning rate to avoid divergence. When you train with a batch size of 1 it becomes really important to avoid this kind of gradient explosions, because a single sample may substantially mess up your descent towards the optimum.

Example output:

```
Epoch  0    Loss: 0.130379
Epoch  1    Loss: 0.123007
Epoch  2    Loss: 0.117352
Epoch  3    Loss: 0.112991
Epoch  4    Loss: 0.109615
Epoch  5    Loss: 0.106992
Epoch  6    Loss: 0.104948
Epoch  7    Loss: 0.103353
Epoch  8    Loss: 0.102105
Epoch  9    Loss: 0.101127
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the answer. But I tried implementing stochastic gradient descent, MSE is the mean of all errors over all points... that should be after each epoch...while stochastic gradient descent is on a single point..at least that's what i learnt in class

Comment: Oh, ok, my bad. In that case, you still had the math wrong, but not by much. I'll update the answer.

Comment: thanks for the answer though.. if we accumulate the loss over all the  points then dividind is the way to go.. but sgd should also work .. i don't know .. https://www.reddit.com/r/learnmachinelearning/new/ i also put the question on reddit ..

Comment: See the update on the bottom of my answer, it should work now.

Comment: Thanks!! I lowered the learning rate to 0.001, 0.0001 and it works..loss is decreasing. Are there any reading materials on these gradient explosion issues in machine learning.. or how to divide into batches...those things are mentioned everywhere but there is no basic introduction that I could find. Thanks again!

Comment: Glad I could help! Cheers and good luck with learning machine learning :)